# Is it possible to construct a $3*3$ MDS matrix in $GF(2^4)$?

Tags: block-cipher, mds

I'm trying to construct a minimal MDS matrix for a toy cipher. I'm not entirely sure, how the various code parameters are tied to my block size, and how exactly is the binary matrix formed, when you have a generator polynomial.

I'm also having a hard time in understanding what's the smallest field and matrix size, where MDS makes sense.

Comment: And how about $GF(2^3)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A matrix $M$ of order $n$ is an MDS (Maximum Distance Separable) matrix if and only if every sub-matrix of $M$ is non-singular. Therefore, if you have an $n\times n$ MDS matrix $M$, constructing the $(n-1)\times (n-1)$ MDS matrix $M'$ is so easy. $M'$ can be constructed by choosing an arbitrary $(n-1)\times (n-1)$ sub-matrix of $M$. [Here](https://ai2-s2-pdfs.s3.amazonaws.com/322f/1cb6509f0847e71dc84685b457285ebe563e.pdf) you can find some information about constructing the MDS matrices over $GF(2^q)$.

Comment: Is the MDS matrix supposed to bin the output to certain subset of the input bits (+ identity)? I don't see how the distribution of hamming distances could be evenly distributed.

Comment: About the document you linked: This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

Comment: I'm getting access denied while accessing the link.